# Why is a photon's energy directly proportional to its frequency?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, photons, frequency

Is this a postulate, or derivable from something else? I've always seen it as some sort of premise, but is it really? I know it was Planck who originally wrote the relation: was it a postulate or a result?

Comment: Energy is proportional to frequency in classical waves.

Comment: @JonCuster  Hmmm... I see that it's proportional to square of the frequency and directly to wavelength and square of amplitude. https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-1/pages/16-4-energy-and-power-of-a-wave  That makes the relationship different from the photon energy relationship.  I know you didn't explicitly say there was a connection, but making the comment seems to infer it.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/583091/does-the-energy-of-a-sound-wave-depend-on-frequency

Comment: When you seriously consider a photon a particle then you can easily imagine it with properties that can convert to energy. A photon has a frequency and that could be an oscillating action. So the faster it cycles, the more energy it has. A photon frequency of 600Thz has twice the energy as a photon frequency of 300Thz

Comment: For a classical mechanical wave in a linear environment, with amplitude held constant, increasing the frequency results in more elastic energy per unit time crossing a given boundary.

Answer (score 2):

The quantum energy idea was a function fitting trick that Planck tried for absorption and emission of radiation and got a good fitting function. He didn't like it.

Einstein used the idea in the photoelectric effect and was able to explain both the intensity and maximum wavelength cutoff behavior, pointing to a good model for behavior of light, i.e., quantized energy linearly proportional to frequency, with no other variables like velocity or amplitude (unlike classical mechanical waves).

It was an *ad hoc* attempt to build a model, and it worked.  It's extremely well supported by experimental evidence and models built on its use work extremely well. Something which has moved from hypothesis to postulate, but has, as of today, no fundamental theoretical basis that the relationship was strictly with frequency. It was purely an educated guess on Planck's part. Undoubtedly he had tried other functions of frequency, or frequency and wavelength, but they didn't work.